# Compare: JMX vs JMS

Tags: java, jms, messaging, jmx

I thought JMX was a specification and JMS was more like an implementation. I was asked the difference between the two and the questioner disagreed with this. I read about it and understood both are specifications. And saw ***"JMX is a monitoring spec, not a publish/subscribe spec.You could beat it
into a publish/subscribe model but that is more what JMS is supposed to do
for you."*** What does this exactly mean? And what is their difference and when to go for one or the other and both.

Comment: Well, like you quoted "JMX is a monitoring spec, not a publish/subscribe spec" so use JMX for monitoring and JMS for pub/sub messaging.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Thank you for the comment. But i was looking for some details on the differences and preferences between the two specifications.

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting from Wikipedia.

> "The Java Message Service (JMS) API is a Java Message Oriented Middleware (MOM) API for sending messages between two or more clients."

In simple terms: it is for passing messages.

> "Java Management Extensions (JMX) is a Java technology that supplies tools for managing and monitoring applications, system objects, devices (such as printers) and service-oriented networks."

In simple terms: it is for monitoring things.

> What is their difference and when to go for one or the other and both.

If you read the above, that should be self evident.

- You would use JMS when you are building an system that needs (reliable, robust, resilient) message passing between different components (typically) on different computers.
- You would JMX when you are implementing monitoring for your system.

(Obviously there are alternatives for both.)

---

> I saw *"JMX is a monitoring spec, not a publish/subscribe spec. You could beat it into a publish/subscribe model but that is more what JMS is supposed to do for you."*  What does this exactly mean?

It is difficult without seeing the context, but I think this is a *response* to someone else suggesting the JMX *could* be used to support publish-subscribe ... for something.  And the guy who wrote this seems to be saying "bad idea: use JMS".

Taken out of context, it is pretty meaningless.  I'd advise not trying to extract deep meaning ....